# php tressract exec nopt working

Tags: php, tesseract

This is working 
exec('C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe');

But this is not working :--

> var_dump(exec('C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public\documents\EnglishSample.png stdout',$output , $return ) );
>   var_dump($output ,$return);

returning empty string and int(1) , I also have tried all permutation combination but nothing working

Sever OS : Windows with XAMPP  , Really Really not understanding this.

Comment: Are you displaying the $output variable somewhere ? If not, you should.

Comment: This question does not fit the StackOverflow's rules because it's too broad and will attract only opinion based answers (so expect it to be closed). Please, go to the: http://stackoverflow.com/help, then read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.